# Arraylist in Session

Tags: asp.net

I have some arraylists in a page which I need to access in a Class file. How can I get these Arraylists in the class file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumming that this class file you are talking about is a code behind file then you can use the Session object almost like an array and cram something in there.

```
Session["MyArrayList"] = new ArrayList();
```

and retrieve using the same

```
tmpArrayList = (ArrayList)Session["MyArrayList"];
```

on another page.